# tomcat7 beginner- using mod_jk with multiple different domains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-jk, tomcat

I am setting up a server where "domain1.com" and "domain2.com" should be served by Apache HTML/PHP server, while "app.domain1.com" and "domain3.com" should be served by Apache Tomcat.

I want to accomplish this using Mod_JK, and I found some useful information regarding config of mod_jk (with the aid of tomcat's workers)... but how do I configure for the specific scenario I have described above, wherein one domain is shared b/w Apache and Tomcat, one domain is served by Apache while a third domain is entirely served by Tomcat?

Comment: from what I read, we can redirect any request for servlets/jsps/other static files to specific 'workers'- however what i dont understand is, where do i specify the specific domain for which i want requests to be sent to one worker, (i.e. app1.domain1.com->worker1 and app2.domain2.com->worker2)-- the syntax for the example i read is something like "JkMount  /examples/servlet/* worker1" But I cannot see anything to specify the domain on which request is being made...hence I am confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You place the JkMount directives inside the httpd.conf virtual host you want them to apply to.